# Episerver : Error: multipleDefine when going to Edit mode

Tags: episerver

I'm getting the following error when going to edit mode.

```
Error: multipleDefine                                                            dojo.js:15                                                                 
at _f (dojo.js:15:436)
at _f6 (dojo.js:15:15989)
at dojo.js:15:16572
at _9 (dojo.js:15:328)
at _7b (dojo.js:15:16543)
at _f0 (dojo.js:15:14659)
at HTMLScriptElement._10a (dojo.js:15:17619)
```

According to the community forums, this is happening because of conflict between Jquery-related libraries when trying to register some function twice.

I have dojo.js and jquery.js file which is used by the plugging I'm developing.

How we can easily find the exact library or point this is happening? Any way to get detailed error messages about what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Episerver already includes jQuery in the UI, so preferably you'd implement your plugin using that version without adding your own.

If that's not possible, you can use `noConflict` for loading your jQuery version in addition to the one loaded by Episerver: [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)